# How to insert one static and multiple dynamic values with foreach loops in mysql table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

In my form, I have a field named `Product` and a button named `Add new` to add 2 fields on each click named `Weight` and `Unit price`. Now, how do I `INSERT` the values of this form in my mysql table using `php`? How do I loop the `product` value for each inputs of `Weight` and `Unit price` value?

This is an example of something that I'm trying to achieve: Product has one value `Rice` and 2 groups of `Weight` and `Unit price` values, `10, 50` and `20, 45` respectively. What would be the `php` section for looping the `Rice` 2 times as there are 2 groups of inputs in the `Available options` and the `sql` to `INSERT` the value to the mysql table (structure described below)?

[image: Sample]

MySQL table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `weight` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here, ID is the `PRIMARY KEY` and set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

This is the `jquery` and `html` part of the form:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
        var count = 0;

        $('p#add_field').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                '<div>\n\
                   <label>Weight</label><input type="text" id="weight_' + count + '" name="weight[]' + '"/>\n\
                  <label>Unit price</label><input type="text" id="price_' + count + '" name="price[]' + '"/>\n\
                <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br>'
            );
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
   <label>Product</label><input type="text" id="product" name="product"><br>
   <div id="container" class="input_fields_wrap">
      <label>Available options:</label>
      <div>
         <p id="add_field"><button type="button" href="#"><span>Add new</span></button></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit">Save to database</button>
</form>
```

This is the sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6p2kvbxL/). What should be the php action codes for this form to function?

Comment: you have to create a php page to insert the row in the db with mysqli functions and SQL. The page name must be in the action value of the form

Comment: Actually I was asking a sample of what that php would be. Thanks.

Comment: When the page loads, how many sets of `weight` and `price` rows are present by default?

Comment: By default no set of `weight` and `price` row is present. Here is a sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6p2kvbxL/). @Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can use below code in PHP

```
<?php
for($ri=0; $ri<count($_POST["weight"]); $ri++){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO product_table (product_name, weight, price) VALUES ('".$_POST["product"]."', '".$_POST["weight"][$ri]."', '".$_POST["price"][$ri]."')";

   //Execute $sql in here with your connection 
}
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php
for($ri=0; $ri<count($_POST["weight"]); $ri++){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO product_table (product_name, weight, price) VALUES ('".$_POST["product"]."', '".$_POST["weight"][$ri]."', '".$_POST["price"][$ri]."')";

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you update the full php if the connection structure is: 
`<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$conn->close();
?>` Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for effort, but it returns a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'` in the line `for($ri=0; $ri<count($_POST["weight"]; $ri++){`. Any help?

Comment: Because of I found the missing bracket ")" for($ri=0; $ri<count($_POST["weight"]); $ri++){ change this

Comment: Wow! It solves the error but it isn't inserting the product name value in the row `product_name` into bd. It leaves blank.

Comment: Please check <input type="text" id="product" name="product"><br> this your element name is "product" hence it should be same name in here $_POST["product"]. If you can not find the problem then print_r($_POST) and send to me the result.

Comment: I've given the working update based on your suggestion. It works fine now. Thanks a lot for your effort. I really appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use what I've been using for these kind of issues.

Update your form to be :-

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="0">
   <label>Product</label><input type="text" id="product" name="product"><br>
   <div id="container" class="input_fields_wrap">
      <label>Available options:</label>
      <div>
         <p id="add_field"><button type="button" href="#"><span>Add new</span></button></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit">Save to database</button>
</form>
```

You notice I've added a hidden field called `count`. The count variable will keep a check of how many rows and columns will be added.

Your JS would then become :-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");

        $('p#add_field').click(function(e) {
            var count = $("#count").val();//get the current value of count variable
            e.preventDefault();
            count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                '<div>\n\
                   <label>Weight</label><input type="text" id="weight_' + count + '" name="weight_' + count + '"/>\n\
                  <label>Unit price</label><input type="text" id="price_' + count + '" id="price_' + count + '"/>\n\
                <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br>'
            );
            //now update back the count variable value
            $("#count").val(count);
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
</script>
```

So now everytime fields are added, their names becomes `weight_countVal` and `price_countVal` which could easily be accessed via backend.

Your backend php could look like :-

```
$totalRows = $_POST['count']; //the hidden variable keeping count of total rows

for($i=1;$i<=$totalRows;$i++)
{
  $weight = $_POST['weight_'.$i];
  $price = $_POST['price_'.$i];
  //run your insert commands here 
}
```

Comment: Wow! This could be another interesting solution. Thanks a lot for your effort. I really appreciate the help. :)